# Alarm & Push Notification not working on Vivo Phone

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-alarms

On Vivo phones as soon as I clear my app from recent history, my app get forced stopped and then push notification is not received by my app also the alarm does not get triggered. 
This issue is only on Vivo phones. I tested this on Vivo Y53 and Vivo Y21. On both devices I found this issue. My app is working fine for other devices like Samsung, Motorola, Pixel...

Comment: The issue comes with Xiaomi phones too. There must some "Auto Start" settings somewhere hidden in the Phone Settings (The Xiaomi does have it for sure). Allow your app to Auto Start and you will not observe this issue.

Comment: I am building notification on vivo v11 using notification builder but notification is not display is there any solution ?